# Does three medians determine a triangle?

Tags: triangles, median

If given three medians, is there only one triangle that has these three medians? How do I prove that?

Comment: Also, if three medians do determine one triangle, how do you express the median in terms of the side lengths?

Comment: In one sense the answer is clearly "no": From the point where the three medians intersect, go along each median in the direction of the vertex, but go twice as far as the vertex.  There you have another triangle with the same three medians.  But it has the same shape. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't understand, if I follow each median twice as far as the vertex, won't the median length change?

Comment: If a triangle is given, any homothetic triangle with G (center of gravity) the center of homothety has the same medians.

Comment: @IsabelZhong : Yes $\ldots$ I was construing the question a bit differently. $\qquad$

Comment: If the medians were to remain the same length, would there be only one triangle with medians that length?

Comment: Yes, see http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Median.htm.

Comment: Won't the change of centroid mean different median length?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies about the lack of a diagram. It is important that you supply it.

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and let $M_a$ be the midpoint of side $BC$. Let $\theta=\angle AM_aB$. Then $\angle AM_aC=180^\circ -\theta$. Let $m_a$ be the length of the median $AM_a$.

By the Cosine Law applied to $\triangle AM_aB$ we have
$$c^2=(a/2)^2+m_a^2-2(a/2)(m_a)\cos\theta.$$
Similarly, we have
$$b^2=(a/2)^2+m_a^2-2(a/2)(m_a)\cos(180^\circ -\theta).$$
Adding, we get, since $\cos(180^\circ-\theta)=-\cos\theta$, that
$$b^2+c^2=a^2/2+2m_a^2,$$
so 
$$2b^2+2c^2-a^2=4m_a^2.$$
We get similar equations for the other medians. Now given $m_a$, $m_b$, and $m_c$ we can solve the system of linear equations for $a^2$, $b^2$, and $c^2$.

*Remark*: Note that given three lengths, these lengths are not necessarily the lengths of the medians of a triangle. In terms of our equations, there may not be positive solutions for $a^2,b^2,c^2$. This is geometrically obvious, since it is clear that there is no triangle with medians $1,1,1000$. In fact the medians of any triangle themselves form a triangle, so satisfy the triangle inequality.